# Monthly pass for traveling between Leuven and Brussels

Tags: belgium, brussels, leuven

I am going to start work in Brussels but my place of residence is in Leuven. Is there a monthly ticket that allows me to commute daily between these two cities? And how much does it cost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [journey railcard](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/railcards/railcard-fixed-journey.aspx) seems to fit your needs. For Leuven-Brussels, the price is €106 on a monthly basis, but you should get most of that reimbursed by your employer.

Comment: Depending on where in Brussels it is, it might be interesting to add the supplement MIVB/STIB (€49 for a month) which allows for unlimited travel on the STIB/MIVB network (except Bourget-Airport).

Comment: I think that would also be a good option, since I would need to travel inside Brussels as well